# Permutations, Combinations and Geometry

Tags: probability

I have to calculate the probability of, choosing 2 random vertices of the prism, those vertices belonging to a line that's parallel to the axis 0z. Here is the prism:
[image]

I did:

- $p(line D,A) = \frac{^4C_2}{^6C_2}$
- $p(line E,B) = \frac{^4C_2}{^6C_2}$
  $$\frac{^4C_2+ ^4C_2}{^6C_2} = \frac{12}{15} = \frac{4}{5}$$

However, my book says the solution should be $\frac{1}{5}$, which happens to be $1-\frac{4}{5}$

- What did I do wrong?
- Why am I supposed to use $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$ instead of
  $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to use the denominator ${}^6C_2 = 15$; this counts the total number of possible pairs of the $6$ vertices.

For the numerator, count the number of vertical pairs. (The number of pairs of vertices that equal {A,D} is $1$, not ${}^4C_2$.) You successfully identified {A,D} and {B,E}, but that only gives $\frac{2}{15}$; there is one more.

Comment: So my mistake was that I forgot {C,0} and I used $^4C_2$ instead of $^2C_2$ to calculate the probability. But I still don't understand something. Look at this picture: http://imgur.com/a/IGR8b Why is it that the correct table, in this context, is table II and not table I?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire Table I is ordered pairs, where (A,B) and (B,A) are considered different. Table II is unordered pairs, where {A,B} = {B,A}.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom 62$ ways to pick two vertices, of which $3$ respect the condition ($3$ vertical edges), hence probability $3/15$.