# Change problem from combination to permutation

Tags: probability

I have this problem:

> Randomly choose 2 vertices of
>   the prism. Calculate the probability that those vertices both belong to a line that's parallel to the
>   axis 0z.

Here is a picture of the prism:

[image]
The answer is 
$$\frac{^2C_2+ ^2C_2+^2C_2}{^6C_2} = \frac{3}{15} = \frac{1}{5}$$

- My question is, how would you change this problem so that instead of
  using $$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$$ you would have to use
  $$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$$ to solve this problem?

I drew some tables so it is easier to visualise the sets 
[image]
**Basically I want that to solve this problem, table I is used instead of table one.**

This question is a follow-up of [Permutations, Combinations and Geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1967042/permutations-combinations-and-geometry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ask: "Randomly choose four different vertices in order (v1,v2,v3,v4). What is the probability that they are arranged in clockwise order around one of the rectangular faces (viewing the face from the outside towards the center of the prism?"

The key in changing from combination to permutation is for it to be important in what order the points are selected.

The solution is:
\begin{equation} \frac{4\times3}{^6P_4} = \frac{12}{360} = \frac{1}{30} \end{equation}

Comment: Why did you use 4*3?  I think you are only counting the faces that are rectangular. What about the triangular ones?

Comment: In that case, would the solution be $\frac{^4A_2+^3A_2}{^6A_4}$?

Comment: A is the same as the P you used in your answer.

Comment: I edited to include only the rectangular faces. It doesn't make sense to have the triangular faces because there are four points. We could also choose three points and ask the same question, but include the triangle.  Then the answer is (4x3+3x2)/P(6,3)